# closed and discrete subset of a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

Is every closed and discrete subset of a metric space uniformly discrete?

I tried searching for a counterexample but could not find any.

Comment: How about $\{1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \ldots\}$ in the space $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ with the usual metric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the metric space $(0,1]$ in the usual metric.

Then $A = \{\frac1n: n =1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is closed and discrete but not uniformly so.